# Cognos Reporting - Generate report only if condition is met

Tags: reporting, cognos-8

Is it possible to prevent a cognos report from being generated if some value say flag is set to false and only generate when flag is set to true. This value needs to be accessed within report studio.

Answer (score 0):

- Create a query which pulls this value
- Create a boolean variable against this value
- Drag a conditional block from the toolbox in the Page area of the report
- Set the "Block Variable" property to the Variable and check the values for it to be rendered
- Create the report items (lists, crosstabs, charts) inside the conditional block
- Optionally repeat for header/footer if you want to handle them separately